# Header files not found in Atom editor for C++

Tags: c++, atom-editor, linter

I'm trying to use the Atom editor for writing C++ code. I want to use the linter-gcc package, but I keep getting the error that it cannot find my header files.

I have tried going into the linter-gcc settings and adding in the GCC Include Paths the following:

```
-/, ./, ./include
```

Here are my linter-gcc settings currently:

[image: linter-gcc settings]

and you can see here the editor where the issue arises and on the left is the directory I'm working in

[image: editor]

Comment: Consider running your `g++` command on the command line. Make that right first. Then configure your IDE

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch what do you mean by this sorry? I can use 'g++ brownian_bridge_min.cpp -o brownian_bridge_min.o -I include/ -std=c++2a' to compile if I add a main() function

Comment: You forgot `-g -Wall`  as options to your `g++`  command

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes I did sorry. But do you know how to get rid of this warning on atom? I know I can still compile the file from g++ since I'm actually supplying the include headers, but I want the error to be gone on my editor

Comment: The `linter-gcc` warning is accurate: the header file is not being referenced by path correctly. The package is functioning correctly, and this is not a config issue, but rather a code issue.

Comment: @MattSchuchard oh right, I thought changing the settings in the 'GCC Include Paths' made linter-gcc look for the include files when writing?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-gcc/issues/61

> You have to add the project root to your include directories. If you
> simply copy and paste the linter-gcc command into the terminal, you'll
> see the same error. The solution is to add the path to your include
> paths to the GCC Include paths setting. So if you have in your project
> root a folder called include that contains your header files, you need
> ti write ./include in your GCC Include paths settings.
> Generally, it's good practice to put your header files in a folder
> called include in your project root. Then you can simply write
> ./include in your GCC Include paths setting so the compiler finds the
> header files.

In sumary, try to put only ./include in your gcc-linter package settings, in both fields for includes:
[gcc-linter settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5FbJ.png)

After that, go back to your file and click cntrl+s or just save it again. It will run the linter again and the issue will be gone (maybe you did not run the linter again after adding the includes as you showed in your comment, so that is why you kept seeing the error)